Minzinc does not return optimal solution
Main question
Context: I specified an ILP encoding like the following:
<some preceding constraints bounding all variables in the objective term>

constraint <objective term> >= c;

solve maximize <objective term>;

Now, the weird thing is that I was able to derive multiple encodings of the form, where increasing the constant c would increase the final value of <objective term>. Still, the solver says the solution is optimal (independent of the value chosen for c). To the best of my understanding this last constraint should not matter. The objective value should always be maximal. The constraint only restricts the amount of satisfying solutions. (As a side note: If c is too high it returns "UNSATISFIABLE", so the solution seems to be bounded.)
Clarification: Increasing c here refers to non-marginal steps. E.g. in the encoding below we can increase c from 1.0 to 2.0 to 3.0 to get an increase of a whole integer step in the resulting objective value. To the best of my understanding this lies far outside the tolerances the solvers are working with.
Question: Is there any general explanation for such a behavior? Are there any conditions that need to be met by an encoding for the solver to return a maximal solution? (I was thinking that I may wrote down something similar to a term that causes undefined behavior in programming languages like C. If such a thing exists.)

A concrete encoding
The encodings I create are generated automatically and start at 10k+ constraints. The following is an encoding I minified manually to the extend I could and cleaned up to make it more comprehensible:
%%%%%%
%%
%% Declare variables of the
%% actual underlying constraints
%%
%%%%%%

var -1e+08..1e+08: v0;
var -1e+08..1e+08: v1;
var -1e+08..1e+08: v2;
var -1e+08..1e+08: v3;
var -1e+08..1e+08: v4;
var -1e+08..1e+08: v5;
var -1e+08..1e+08: v6;
var -1e+08..1e+08: v7;
var -1e+08..1e+08: v8;
var -1e+08..1e+08: v9;
var -1e+08..1e+08: v10;
var -1e+08..1e+08: v11;
var -1e+08..1e+08: v12;
var -1e+08..1e+08: v13;
var -1e+08..1e+08: v14;
var -1e+08..1e+08: v15;
var -1e+08..1e+08: v16;
var -1e+08..1e+08: v17;
var -1e+08..1e+08: v18;
var -1e+08..1e+08: v19;
var -1e+08..1e+08: v20;
var -1e+08..1e+08: v21;
var -1e+08..1e+08: v22;
var -1e+08..1e+08: v23;
var -1e+08..1e+08: v24;
var -1e+08..1e+08: v25;
var -1e+08..1e+08: v26;
var -1e+08..1e+08: v27;
var -1e+08..1e+08: v28;
var -1e+08..1e+08: v29;
var -1e+08..1e+08: v30;
var -1e+08..1e+08: v31;

%%%%%%
%%
%% Declare variables for the minimum
%% linearization according to
%% https://or.stackexchange.com/a/1174 
%% (Variable names are the same as in the code)
%%
%%%%%%

var -1e+20..1e+20: x1_0;
var -1e+20..1e+20: x2_0;
var -1e+20..1e+20: X_0;
var -1e+20..1e+20: x1_1;
var -1e+20..1e+20: x2_1;
var -1e+20..1e+20: X_1;
var -1e+20..1e+20: x1_2;
var -1e+20..1e+20: x2_2;
var -1e+20..1e+20: X_2;
var -1e+20..1e+20: x1_3;
var -1e+20..1e+20: x2_3;
var -1e+20..1e+20: X_3;
var -1e+20..1e+20: x1_4;
var -1e+20..1e+20: x2_4;
var -1e+20..1e+20: X_4;
var -1e+20..1e+20: x1_5;
var -1e+20..1e+20: x2_5;
var -1e+20..1e+20: X_5;
var -1e+20..1e+20: x1_6;
var -1e+20..1e+20: x2_6;
var -1e+20..1e+20: X_6;
var -1e+20..1e+20: x1_7;
var -1e+20..1e+20: x2_7;
var -1e+20..1e+20: X_7;
var -1e+20..1e+20: x1_8;
var -1e+20..1e+20: x2_8;
var -1e+20..1e+20: X_8;
var -1e+20..1e+20: x1_9;
var -1e+20..1e+20: x2_9;
var -1e+20..1e+20: X_9;
var -1e+20..1e+20: x1_10;
var -1e+20..1e+20: x2_10;
var -1e+20..1e+20: X_10;
var {0,1}: y_0;
var {0,1}: y_1;
var {0,1}: y_2;
var {0,1}: y_3;
var {0,1}: y_4;
var {0,1}: y_5;
var {0,1}: y_6;
var {0,1}: y_7;
var {0,1}: y_8;
var {0,1}: y_9;
var {0,1}: y_10;
float: M = 1e+09;


%%%%%%
%%
%% Declare constraints for the minimum
%% linearization 
%% (repeated for multiple minima)
%%
%%%%%%

constraint X_0 <= x1_0;
constraint X_0 <= x2_0;
constraint X_0 >= x1_0 - M + M*y_0;
constraint X_0 >= x2_0 - M*y_0;

constraint X_1 <= x1_1;
constraint X_1 <= x2_1;
constraint X_1 >= x1_1 - M + M*y_1;
constraint X_1 >= x2_1 - M*y_1;

constraint X_2 <= x1_2;
constraint X_2 <= x2_2;
constraint X_2 >= x1_2 - M + M*y_2;
constraint X_2 >= x2_2 - M*y_2;

constraint X_3 <= x1_3;
constraint X_3 <= x2_3;
constraint X_3 >= x1_3 - M + M*y_3;
constraint X_3 >= x2_3 - M*y_3;

constraint X_4 <= x1_4;
constraint X_4 <= x2_4;
constraint X_4 >= x1_4 - M + M*y_4;
constraint X_4 >= x2_4 - M*y_4;

constraint X_5 <= x1_5;
constraint X_5 <= x2_5;
constraint X_5 >= x1_5 - M + M*y_5;
constraint X_5 >= x2_5 - M*y_5;

constraint X_6 <= x1_6;
constraint X_6 <= x2_6;
constraint X_6 >= x1_6 - M + M*y_6;
constraint X_6 >= x2_6 - M*y_6;

constraint X_7 <= x1_7;
constraint X_7 <= x2_7;
constraint X_7 >= x1_7 - M + M*y_7;
constraint X_7 >= x2_7 - M*y_7;

constraint X_8 <= x1_8;
constraint X_8 <= x2_8;
constraint X_8 >= x1_8 - M + M*y_8;
constraint X_8 >= x2_8 - M*y_8;

constraint X_9 <= x1_9;
constraint X_9 <= x2_9;
constraint X_9 >= x1_9 - M + M*y_9;
constraint X_9 >= x2_9 - M*y_9;

constraint X_10 <= x1_10;
constraint X_10 <= x2_10;
constraint X_10 >= x1_10 - M + M*y_10;
constraint X_10 >= x2_10 - M*y_10;

%%%%%%
%%
%% Constraint encodings of each two terms set to x1_{i}, x2_{i} 
%% whose minimum X_{i} shall be restricted
%%
%%%%%%

constraint v6 - v7 - v14 + v16 = x1_0;
constraint v2 + v5 + v6 + v13 + v16 + v19 + v22 + v25 + v28 + v31 = x2_0;
constraint X_0 <= 1;

constraint v6 - v8 - v11 + v13 = x1_1;
constraint v2 + v5 + v6 + v13 + v16 + v19 + v22 + v25 + v28 + v31 = x2_1;
constraint X_1 <= 1;

constraint v3 - v4 = x1_2;
constraint v2 + v3 + v10 + v13 + v16 + v19 + v22 + v25 + v28 + v31 = x2_2;
constraint X_2 <= 1;

constraint - v3 + v4 = x1_3;
constraint v2 + v4 + v10 + v13 + v16 + v19 + v22 + v25 + v28 + v31 = x2_3;
constraint X_3 <= 1;

constraint v0 - v1 = x1_4;
constraint v0 + v5 + v10 + v13 + v16 + v19 + v22 + v25 + v28 + v31 = x2_4;
constraint X_4 <= 1;

constraint v7 - v9 - v26 + v28 = x1_5;
constraint v2 + v3 + v7 + v13 + v16 + v19 + v22 + v25 + v28 + v31 = x2_5;
constraint X_5 <= 1;

constraint v7 - v9 - v23 + v25 = x1_6;
constraint v0 + v5 + v7 + v13 + v16 + v19 + v22 + v25 + v28 + v31 = x2_6;
constraint X_6 <= 1;

constraint v8 - v9 - v17 + v19 = x1_7;
constraint v0 + v5 + v8 + v13 + v16 + v19 + v22 + v25 + v28 + v31 = x2_7;
constraint X_7 <= 1;

constraint v26 - v27 - v29 + v31 = x1_8;
constraint v2 + v3 + v10 + v13 + v14 + v19 + v22 + v25 + v26 + v31 = x2_8;
constraint X_8 <= 1;

constraint v23 - v24 - v29 + v31 = x1_9;
constraint v1 + v5 + v10 + v13 + v14 + v19 + v22 + v23 + v28 + v31 = x2_9;
constraint X_9 <= 1;

constraint v20 - v21 - v29 + v31 = x1_10;
constraint v2 + v4 + v10 + v11 + v16 + v19 + v20 + v25 + v28 + v31 = x2_10;
constraint X_10 <= 1;

%%%%%%
%%
%% Additional constraints
%%
%%%%%%

constraint v2 + v5 + v10 + v13 + v16 + v19 + v22 + v25 + v28 + v29 <= 0;

constraint v0 <= v2;
constraint v1 <= v2;
constraint v3 <= v5;
constraint v4 <= v5;
constraint v6 <= v10;
constraint v7 <= v10;
constraint v8 <= v10;
constraint v9 <= v10;
constraint v11 <= v13;
constraint v12 <= v13;
constraint v14 <= v16;
constraint v15 <= v16;
constraint v17 <= v19;
constraint v18 <= v19;
constraint v20 <= v22;
constraint v21 <= v22;
constraint v23 <= v25;
constraint v24 <= v25;
constraint v26 <= v28;
constraint v27 <= v28;
constraint v29 <= v31;
constraint v30 <= v31;

%%%%%%
%%
%% Define the objective term.
%% (For convenience as the term
%% is repeatedly used below)
%%
%%%%%%

var float: objective_term;
constraint objective_term = v0 + v3 + v6 + v12 + v15 + v18 + v21 + v24 + v27 + v30;

%%%%%%
%%
%% The following constraint is unneeded and 
%% only inserted for debugging:
%% Objective value 1 is returned for >= 0
%% When modifying to >= 2, the objective value becomes 2
%% When modifying to >= 3, the objective value becomes 3
%% (2 is the actual maximum, as far as I can tell)
%%
%%%%%%
constraint objective_term >= 0;

solve maximize objective_term;
output ["objective value =\(objective_term)\n"];

The encoding is using https://or.stackexchange.com/a/1174 to encode an ILP with minima. (Variable names in the encoding correspond to the names used in the linked post.) The constraints are split accordingly into the minimization constraints and the others.
The constraint for the objective value is typically not generated. I added it for debugging.

Info about technical setup and some debugging attempts:
For me the unexpected behavior occurs with Minizinc 2.8.4 and Cplex 22.1.1. I also tried the native Cplex API, which makes me think that it can't be a Minizinc bug. While the behavior is solver specific for this encoding above, I was able to notice similar things for different encodings. E.g. I generated one that worked (= always returned the maximal solution) with Cplex but did not with Coin-BC. Here the adjusted constraint is a bit different. When the binary variables are forced to be always 1, the solver returns a better solution. (Though this is strictly more constraining.)
1st version (returns objective value 1):
https://gist.github.com/PLauerRocks/2bee530ba8fda67f3ae7a220a81ecd48/ddf9962e7c86641bc5944bf6c13a52824c05588c
2nd version (returns objective value 2, but is more constraining): https://gist.github.com/PLauerRocks/2bee530ba8fda67f3ae7a220a81ecd48
Diff shown by revision comparison: https://gist.github.com/PLauerRocks/2bee530ba8fda67f3ae7a220a81ecd48/revisions

Unless it is essential for the syntax of the solver s\1 * \\ s\+ -\-\ would greatly improves legibility. Also the first two constraints would appear to simplify to v32=1.

@MartinBrown thank you for your feedback. I improved the encoding accordingly. I agree that it looks better now. If there is something else I can do, let me know.

This sounds like the well-known behaviour of MILP solvers where, because of their scaling and the general rounding in floating point operations, they are not guaranteed to return an optimal result

@Dekker1 Would the solver still claim the solution to be optimal in this case? If caused by floating point operations can the gap really be as large as 2.0, like in the example? Are there ways of minimizing this behavior like restricting variable domains to tighter bounds? Sorry if this are basic questions. I am trying my best to understand the problem here. Pointers to other discussions/documentation suffices.

Yes, the solver would still claim for the solution to be optimal. It wouldn't know what types of rounding errors might have occurred. The general guide for floating point operations that I would suggest is: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html, but I'm sure there are some MILP specific guides if you look for them

@Dekker1 I understand that standard floating point operations can be inaccurate in a general programming/hardware contexts. What surprises me is that this could go beyond the optimality guarantees of solvers. The log states CPXPARAM_MIP_Tolerances_MIPGap is set to 1e-08. So the objective value would fall out of the guaranteed optimality range, wouldn't it?  (Just wanting to make sure we are talking about the same thing.) --  I am also fine with realizing that its actually a bug and reporting it somewhere.

@Dekker1 Okay, sorry for questioning this. I understand now. I will write an answer to the post later explaining the problem. Thank you very much for the pointer. It just took me a little longer to understand what you meant/suggested.

Answering the main question:
As Dekker1 pointed out, there are:

problems with  MILP solvers where because of their scaling and the general rounding in floating point
operations, they are not guaranteed to return an optimal result

Apparently this behavior is independent of the defined solver tolerances. And, at least to me, this feels at least comparable to undefined behavior. To provide a concise example, consider the following Minizinc program:
var {0,1}: y;
float: M = 1e+09;

constraint M - M * y + 3 <= 2;

Here we are basically trying to prove that
3 <= 2
or 
3 + big number M <= 2

of which both statements are false. Still, the solver will return y = 0 as a correct solution. (Which is wrong.)
Until now I can not explain why this is the case. Operations with *0 and *1 are typically perfect. So evaluation the LP-normalized term M - M * y <= -1 should not be a problem. Therefore it has to be due to some internals of the solver algorithm. From where it becomes hard to impossible to to judge what the actual problem is and how to fix it.
In fact there are multiple reported encounters where a "big M" value caused similar issues. But I found none with actual suggestions of how to fix or mitigate the problem besides just decreasing M. So I will discuss possible solutions below.
Fixing the concrete encoding / Other big M encodings:
Let's start by stating that simply decreasing M is probably the best solution if it is possible. But what if that's not possible? To the best of my understanding there are some things you can do to at least mitigate the behavior.
The first thing I tried was reasoned by my explanation above that the operations "*0" and "*1" are typically not a problem. By encapsulating them into an extra constraint I wanted to isolate this expression to be perfectly evaluated.
constraint tmp = M - M*y;
constraint 3 + tmp <= 2;

And indeed this already "solved" the problem in the sense that I got the optimal solutions I was looking for. Though, as the constraints are equivalent I would really doubt that this is actually a general fix. An alternative version I would put more trust into would be:
var {0,1}: y;
float: M = 1e+09;
int: M_as_int = 1000000000;
var {M_as_int, 0}: tmp;

constraint tmp = M - M*y;
constraint 3 + tmp <= 2;

where tmp is then forced to be an integer value 0 which can be accurately represented as float and matches the other number range of the constraint 3 + tmp <= 2.
I can not guarantee that this actually fixes the problem, but at least intuitively speaking, this mitigates it. And from some testing I was also not able to reproduce any unexpected behavior in this setting.
Moving away from ILPs:
As stated in the initial post, the reason for using the "big M" constraint was to encode a minimum. And in fact there would have been multiple ways to do this in Minizinc directly and let the flatzinc translation handle the rest for me. Examples are:
Complex constraints with or
constraint M + 3 <= 2 \/ 3 <= 2;

Complex constraints with implies
constraint y = 0 -> M <= 2;
constraint y = 1 -> 3 <= 2;

A similar thing would be possible with Indicator constraints in CPLEX. Into which Minzinc can also translate.
A minimum directly
constraint min(M, 3) <= 2;


As a last side note:

When the value of this parameter is set to level 2,
CPX_DATACHECK_ASSIST, CPLEX turns on both data consistency checking
and modeling assistance. At this level, CPLEX issues warnings at the
start of the optimization about disproportionate values (too large,
too small) in coefficients, bounds, and righthand sides (RHS).

So when natively testing this with CPLEX, enabling this flag would have warned me about too high M values already.
